# ASP.NET ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator, validationsummary

I have a form containing different required field.

I also have a `ValidationSummary`which will display a pop-up when clicking on the submit button if some required fields are not filled in.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="vsValidationSummary" ValidationGroup="DefaultGroup" DisplayMode="BulletList" ForeColor="Red" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
```

When filling all the fields except one (see below the field) the popup is displayed (OK) but with only the message :

```
- Required
```

For other fields there is the name next to "Required"

The field which is failing is the following :

```
<div class="formFieldLine">
     <span class="userFormLabel">
          <ab:FormLabel Colon="false" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlSuperstructureType" Text="<%$ Resources:lbSuperstructureType.Text %>" />
     </span>
     <ab:LabelledDropDownlist ID="ddlSuperstructureType" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSuperstructureTypes" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" CssClass="dropdownSTypeBuyBack" />
     <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvSuperstructureType" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlSuperstructureType" ClientValidationFunction="ddlSelected_Validate" ValidationGroup="DefaultGroup"
                    CssClass="validatorMessage" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Messages,RequiredField %>" OnServerValidate="ddlSelected_Validate"/>
     <br />
</div>
```

Here is a working field

```
<div class="formFieldLine">
     <span class="userFormLabel">
          <ab:FormLabel Colon="false" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="tbLeasingDuration" Text="<%$ Resources:lblLeasingDuration.Text %>" />
     </span>
     <ab:LabelledTextBox ID="tbLeasingDuration" runat="server" MaxLength="100" />
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvfLeasingDuration" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Messages,RequiredField %>" ControlToValidate="tbLeasingDuration" runat="server" ValidationGroup="DefaultGroup" ForeColor="Red" />
     <br />
     <asp:RangeValidator ID="rvLeasingDuration" Type="Double" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Messages,InvalidNumber %>" ControlToValidate="tbLeasingDuration" ValidationGroup="DefaultGroup" runat="server" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="999999999" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" style="margin-left : 212px;"/>
</div>
```

Here is a printscreen of the popup :
[image]

Comment: show us any other filed where it is working fine

Comment: there must be some other logic.just `<%$ Resources:Messages,RequiredField %>` won't print your field name

Comment: The error message is displayed nex to the required field when it is not filled in and should be display in popup when clicking on submit button

Comment: could you put a screenshot?

Comment: @shreesha screenshot added

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the mentioned error message,pass the message which you are required to show...

Comment: The `Error message` in my customValidator ? I cannot modified it, it is displayed next to the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Check your render block - this doesn't look right:

```
<%$ Resources:Messages,RequiredField %>
```

Should it be this?

```
<%= Resources:Messages,RequiredField %>
```

Comment: I confirm you it is `<%$ %>`

Comment: That doesn't look right - try changing the $ to = and see if it works